# Angular Fire Functions calling but not running

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

Ive been working on an ionic project and i am trying to make a direct cloud function call from my app. This call begins execution but does not write the documents i need coded it to write to my database. I cant even tell if the function is running because the console.log statements are not giving any result on my log console. Here is my code for the cloud function on my backend

```
exports.usedDevices = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
 console.log(data);
 console.log(context);
 console.log('This started running');
 admin.firestore()
   .collection('devices/{documentId}')
   .get()
   .then(val=>{
     if(val.empty === false){
       val.forEach(function(snapshot): boolean | void{
         if(snapshot.data() === data){
           return false
         }
       })
        admin.firestore()
        .collection('devices')
        .add(
          data
        )
        .catch(er=>{
          console.log(er);
          return er;
        }) 
        return true
     }
     else{
       admin.firestore()
         .collection('devices')
         .add(
           data
         )
         .catch(er=>{
           console.log(er);
           return er;
         })
         return true
     }
   })
   .catch(er=>{
     console.log(er);
     return er
   })
```

})

And from my application i try calling this function like this

```
 const uid="This is my uid";
const call = this.aff.httpsCallable('usedDevices');
call(uid).toPromise()
.then(res=>{
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(er=>{
  console.log(er);
})
```

I am using a simple 'This is my uid" String to test if my message ever reaches the back end but still not reading the data from my backend. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it in as a object: `{uid: uid}`

Here's a clean-code example:

```
async getUsedDevice(uid) {
   const call = this.aff.httpsCallable('usedDevices');
   
   //                         {uid: uid}   <-- This solves your problem
   const results = await call({uid: uid}).toPromise();
   return results;
}
```

I've put it in an `async` function, converted it to a `promise` and `awaited` for it to resolve. I believe this is the cleanest way to write the code as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try calling your function without the "toPromise()"

```
 const uid="This is my uid";
const call = this.aff.httpsCallable('usedDevices');
call(uid)
.then(res=>{
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(er=>{
  console.log(er);
})
```

Comment: This isn't working, im thinking because you cant call the .then() for a variable which isnt of type Observable. I called Onpromise to change the response to a promise before trying to read the response from my server

Comment: Are you sure about your provider "this.aff" @user10112707

Comment: Yes I am, I can see that the function is being started in my firebase functions log but the data passed isn't showing and it runs without executing any of the commands i wrote